Puzzle with crosses and boxes
This is a question asked from a Reddit user
https://www.reddit.com/r/iqtest/comments/1drjv9i/what_do_you_think/#lightbox

I believe the answer is D.
A green cross without the boxes tangent on it(in each row 1 cross has no boxes on it and the other one has) and 2 pairs of yellow boxes because in first row we have 4 pairs, in 2nd row we have 6 so now it must be different( with D we have 5 pairs). Same goes with columns. 4 in 1st column, 6 in 2nd and 5 in the 3rd.
Furthermore, in each row, regarding the squares with the crosses, we have 1 pair in left box and 1 pair in the right one, in the second we have 2 on the left and 2 on the right, so in the third we must have 1 pair in one of them and 2 on the other so that we have all 3 different combinations (1-1, 2-2 and 1-2 or 2-1)
